# get_browser() array into variables?

Tags: php, get

Im currently playing around with browser detection mainly for statistics from the site and to better design the site in future. No ive been told the best way to go about this is to use the following code which shows all the browser info in an array if all my ini files are in place (which they are)

```
function list_array ($array) {
while (list ($key, $value) = each ($array)) {
$str .= "$brw = <b>$key:</b> $value<br>\n";
}
return $str;
}
echo "$HTTP_USER_AGENT<hr>\n";
$browser = get_browser();
echo list_array ((array) $browser);
```

The then displays this

```
 browser_name_regex: �^mozilla/5\.0 \(.*windows nt 6\.2.*wow64.*\) applewebkit/.* \        (khtml, like gecko\).*chrome/28\..*safari/.*$�
= browser_name_pattern: Mozilla/5.0 (*Windows NT 6.2*WOW64*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like Gecko)*Chrome/28.*Safari/*
= parent: Chrome 28.0
= platform: Win8
= platform_version: 6.2
= win32: 
= win64: 1
= comment: Chrome 28.0
= browser: Chrome
= version: 28.0
= majorver: 28
= minorver: 0
= frames: 1
= iframes: 1
= tables: 1
= cookies: 1
= javascript: 1
= javaapplets: 1
= cssversion: 3
= alpha: 
= beta: 
= win16: 
= backgroundsounds: 
= vbscript: 
= activexcontrols: 
= ismobiledevice: 
= issyndicationreader: 
= crawler: 
= aolversion: 0
```

Now heres were the problem lies all detect browser php plugings or download are overly complicated all im looking to do i seperate iphones ipads android blackberry apple and some of the most basic pieces of information. How can I turn this array into variables that can be used later. for example if i can grab the 2nd 3rd n 4th in the array i will have all the information i want as accurate as i need it all otherways and i seem to get problems with iphones showing as just a mobile device and what not Ive already tried for example

```
if (preg_match('/windows nt 6.2/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Windows 8';
  }
```

and

```
$blackberry = strpos(&ua, 'Android') ? true : false;
```

and looked at
http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php.html
http://www.phpjabbers.com/php-snippet/detect-browser-php.php
http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/2562-php-to-detect-browser-and-operating-system/

Comment: You could do something like `$parent = $browser['parent']`, or you could just keep the `$browser` array itself and whenever you need the 'parent' entry just refer to `$browser['parent']`. Are you really just asking about how to access entries in an array? Take a look at the PHP array [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Firstly, always remember that the User Agent string can lie to you. Don't rely on it. For statistics, I would strongly recommend using an existing tool such as AWStats or Google Analytics. There are some great tools out there already; your own home-built stats system is never going to compete. If you're planning to detect the browser so you can modify the page based on the browser, I'd recommend being very caution about that; there are usually better ways to do achieve the desired result without sniffing the user agent string.

Comment: i have tried just using it like a normal array and get Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /homepages/17/d470555839/htdocs/index.php on line 208

Comment: @JasonDemitri `var_dump` your array and update your question with the results

Comment: Change `get_browser()` to `get_browser(NULL, TRUE)`, if you read the documentation you would of realized that `get_browser()` returns an object instead of an array unless you pass `TRUE` to the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use foreach() instead of each + list. See http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.each.php#63805

Second, you're casting the result of get_browser as an array for your list_array function when you do (array) $browser, that's why it works and why it doesn't create a fatal error.

If you want to use the result of get_browser as an array, you should however use the built in option to do so, ie :

```
$b = get_browser(null, true);
```

The second option here tells get_browser to return an array instead of an object, this should solve your problem of trying to use a class as an array.

You will then be able to use :

```
echo $b['browser'];
```

The default return type for get_browser beeing an object, you would have to use

```
$b = get_browser();
echo $b->browser;
```

if you wanted the same result.

Try reading the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php to get a better understanding of the functions you're using. You will find useful code in the comments aswell.

Finally, as you've been told, you should use an existing API for statistics.

Good luck with your coding.

Comment: THANK YOU that worked like a charm . . .and yes i know there are apis out there but alot are very bloated and contain alot of stuff i dont need so instead of trying to reduce them in size i just wanted to get eh basics from get_browser() so that they can be sent with form submissions and signups helping me to design v2 and also allowing me to warn people about compatibility for example Foundation 4 which im using in my MVC wont work on IE8 and below yes it may be along way round but since im self teching untill college i get to understand the inner working of things people take for granted :)